# Query to make dynamic sorting in Postgres for child elements

Tags: postgresql

I have a data set like below(PostgresQL version 11),I want to add a sorting column to this with decimal points so that i can easily map the parent - child tree in my visualisation.

Any method or query we can do that,Tried with row number and rank but that is not helping.

**Data Set:**

```
Parent      Child
Vitamine    Vitamine
Vitamin D   Vitamin D
Vitamin D   Vitamin D3
Vitamin D   Vitamin D K2
Vitamin D   D3
Vitamin D   Vitamin D 1000
Vitamin D   Vitamin D 10000
Vitamin D   Vitamin D 20000
Vitamin K2  Vitamin K2
Vitamin K2  Vitamin K
Vitamin K2  Vitamin K2 Mk7
Vitamin C   Vitamin C
```

**Expected out put**

```
  Parent      Child             Sort_order
    Vitamine    Vitamine           1
    Vitamin D   Vitamin D          2
    Vitamin D   Vitamin D3         2.1
    Vitamin D   Vitamin D K2       2.2
    Vitamin D   D3                 2.3
    Vitamin D   Vitamin D 1000     2.4
    Vitamin D   Vitamin D 10000    2.5
    Vitamin D   Vitamin D 20000    2.6
    Vitamin K2  Vitamin K2         3
    Vitamin K2  Vitamin K          3.1
    Vitamin K2  Vitamin K2 Mk7     3.2
    Vitamin C   Vitamin C          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following table schema:

```
create table vitamins (
  id serial primary key,
  parent_id integer,
  name varchar(64),
  index smallint
);
```

with the following data:

```
insert into vitamins (id, parent_id, name, index) values
  (1, null, 'Vitamine', 1),
  (2, null, 'Vitamin D', 2),
  (3, 2, 'Vitamin D3', 1),
  (4, 2, 'Vitamin D K2', 2),
  (5, 2, 'D3', 3),
  (6, 2, 'Vitamin D 1000', 4),
  (7, 2, 'Vitamin D 10000', 5),
  (8, 2, 'Vitamin D 20000', 6),
  (9, null, 'Vitamin K2', 3),
  (10, 9, 'Vitamin K', 1),
  (11, 9, 'Vitamin K2 Mk7', 2),
  (12, null, 'Vitamin C', 4)
;
```

We can get the expected output you want with the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursive_vitamins(id, parent_id, index, parent_name, name, ref, sort) AS (
    SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.index, c.name, c.name, c.index::text, lpad(c.index::text, 3, '0')
    FROM vitamins c
    WHERE parent_id is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.index, rc.parent_name, c.name,
           CASE WHEN rc.ref = '' THEN c.index::text
                ELSE (rc.ref || '.' || c.index)
               END, (rc.sort || '.' || lpad(c.index::text, 3, '0'))
    FROM vitamins c, recursive_vitamins rc
    WHERE c.parent_id = rc.id
)

SELECT
    parent_name AS parent,
    name AS child,
    ref AS sort_order
FROM recursive_vitamins
ORDER BY sort;
```

Result:

```
parent      child         sort_order
Vitamine    Vitamine      1
Vitamin D   Vitamin D     2
Vitamin D   Vitamin D3    2.1
Vitamin D   Vitamin D K2  2.2
Vitamin D   D3            2.3
...
```

[(sqlfiddle of the whole thing)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/54060/2)

**Hold up, what's happening here?**

So, we create a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) allowing the query to refer to it's own output.
In the `WITH` query we first select all parents (`parent_id is null`) then we select all childs that refer to the the `parent_id`.

The `ref` field is a concatenation of parent and child index. The `sort` field refers to `index` as well, but it [left-pads](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-string.html) the `index` with `0` to a total length of 3. You could leave this out and just `order by ref`, but if you have an `index` >= `10`, the order would become `1, 10, 10.1, 2` which I would guess you don't want.